# android screen layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-design

i have created three folders for layout , namely layout-large, layout-normal and layout-small. I have tested my apps in two devices namely Moto g2 and Sony c2005.

Moto g2 specifications:
Size    5.0 inches (~68.9% screen-to-body ratio)
Resolution  720 x 1280 pixels (~294 ppi pixel density)

Sony C2005 specifications:
Size    4.0 inches (~57.3% screen-to-body ratio)
Resolution  480 x 854 pixels (~245 ppi pixel density).

I think both devices are using layout-normal files. The issue is layouts display properly on Moto g2 device but not on Sony C2005. Some part of layout missing in Sony c2005.

Below image show how layout appear on Moto G2 and Sony C2005.[image: left MOTO right SONY]

can anybody have solution on this?

Comment: Maybe some would give a better answer in device fragments problem but normally I calculate the ratio basing screen w/h and set target's  LayoutParam. Good luck.

Comment: the solution for this issue is to avoid giving fixed size to layout heights.